# "Тошнить" в значении "медленно ехать"

Tags: этимология

Откуда у слова "тошнить" пошло значение "медленно ехать" (тошнить в левом ряду)?

Answer (score 2):

Мне такое использование слова "тошнить" всегда казалось интуитивно понятным.
Во-первых, тошнота — это что-то медленное, долгое и неприятно-тягучее.
Во-вторых, "тошнить" — это нечто меньшее, чем "рвать". Собственно, поэтому фразы в стиле "вместо того, чтобы ***рвануть*** на обгон, он ***тошнил*** в общем потоке" воспринимаются вполне органично.
Поэтому вряд ли стоит искать у этого значения какое-то *особенное* происхождение.